# Literature for mesopotamian seven-tiered cosmos?

Tags: mesopotamia, reference-request, astrology, cosmogony

Reading up on the (excellent) Gilgamesh epic, I found a note for the 11th tablet (where Uta-Napishti - the 'original' Noah) describes the seven-tiered layout of the Ark. The author appended a note stating that some scholars believe this is a poetic reflection of the seven-tiered structure of the cosmos in which the Babylonians believed.

This sounds very interesting. Does anybody know a good academic source or literature reference for this seven-tiered cosmological structure?

Comment: You might try starting with some of the references listed on the [Wikipedia article on the Seven Heavens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Heavens).

Comment: Ah, interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number seven is used in the Gilgamesh epos 40 times, so it seems more like a special connotation given to the number in general. Some examples:

> You have loved the lion tremendous in strength: seven pits you dug for
>   him, and seven. You have loved the stallion magnificent in battle, and
>   for him you decreed whip and spur and a thong, to gallop seven leagues
>   by force and to muddy the water before he drinks;
>
> If I do what you desire there will be seven years of drought
>   throughout Uruk when corn will be seedless husks. Have you saved grain
>   enough for the people and grass for the cattle? Ishtar replied. ‘I
>   have saved grain for the people, grass for the cattle; for seven years
>   of seedless husks' there is grain and there is grass enough.'
>
> The next day also, in the first light, Gilgamesh lamented; seven days
>   and seven nights he wept for Enkidu, until the worm fastened on him.
>   Only then he gave him up to the earth, for the Anunnaki, the judges,
>   had seized him.

An explanation of your question is detailed [here on the bottom of page 40 and page 41](https://books.google.be/books?id=lKvMeMorNBEC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=seven-tiered+structure+of+the+cosmos+Babylon&source=bl&ots=nBM4W_CrrF#v=onepage&q=seven-tiered%20structure%20of%20the%20cosmos%20Babylon&f=false)

Comment: It seems that the Mesopotamians loved this number in general. I have since found another source which mentions the seven heavens made from different gemstones, in a book called 'Daily Life in Ancient Mesopotamia' by K.R. Nemet-Nejat, but doesn't go into greater detail. This seems to contradict what's written in the book you suggest.